# Accelerate convergence of sequence

Tags: convergence-divergence, rational-numbers, convergence-acceleration

Is it always possible to extract a subsequence from my generic sequence $(q_n)$, such that the convergence of the subsequence to the same limit $r$ is faster then the original?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is yes.

Pick any rate of convergence $r_n$ you want. Then, for each $n$ there exists some $M_n$ such that for all $m >M_n$ we have
$$|a_n-l|<r_n$$

Pick inductively
$$k_n > \max \{ k_1,k_2,..., k_{n-1}, M_n \}$$

Then $a_{k_n}$ is a subsequence and since $k_n >M_n$ we have
$$|a_{k_n} -l| <r_n$$

Comment: So we are basically choosing the natural number $M_n$ so that we make $\epsilon$ small enough (what you called $r_n$) to convergence, at every step, at the rate I want?

Comment: @TheTurtleHermit For each $n$ you set $\epsilon$ to be the rate of convergence at that $n$ and pick one element which satisfies that inequality, yes.